# how to determine the package name of a jar file in Java

Tags: java, import

I was just pushed on board of java.

For an existing jar file log4j.jar (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.zip), I put it under ./lib subfolder, my java source file MyDemo.java is under ./jms/example folder, and I use jms.example as the package name and import log4j classes in my java file:

```
package jms.example;
import org.apache.log4j.*;
```

When I compile using the following command, I got the error:

```
c:\JDK\bin\javac.exe -cp '.;.\lib\log4j.jar' -d .\classes -g .\jms\example\MyDemo.java
```

error: cannot find symbol
    private final Logger logger;

What's wrong in the above code?

In addition, I'm wondering:
* Is package name related with file path? for example, I put my java file under jms/example, is this the reason I have to name the package as jms.example?

When I extract other jar files which are provided by 3rd party, the path to class files is jms/example,and the 3rd party example code use jms.example as package name, and it's consistent with class path jms/example, do they have to be consistent?

- When extract log4j.jar, the path to its class files is org/apache/log4j/, then should I have to use "import org.apache.log4j.*" to import the classes? If I still use jms.example as my package name, will the import prepend it to the class path, i.e., it actually becomes jms.example.org.apache.log4j.*?

Comment: There is no such thing as the package name of a Jar file. Re your last question, no. There's too much confusion here to address.

Comment: @EJP:
This works:  

`import org.apache.log4j.Logger;`  

But if I omit any part of org.apache.log4j, it doesn't work;  

How to know or determine the package name of Logger class? I think it's determined by the file path inside jar file.

Comment: Regarding my previous question: Yes, it's true package name has to be same as its path in the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

The path can't be enclosed with quote; that is, it's wrong in the command:

```
-cp '.;.\lib\log4j.jar'
```

It should be:

```
-cp .;.\lib\log4j.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question:
 *Is package name related with file path? for example, I put my java file under jms/example, is this the reason I have to name the package as jms.example?*
No, you can use any package name, for example:

```
package yyyyjmsxxx.zzzzexamplexxx;
```